# how can I be more specific with express router params

Tags: node.js, express

I currently have a few router routes

```
router.route('/invite/token/:inviteToken')
  .get(function (req, res) {
    res.status(200).json(req.invite);
  });

router.route('/invite/:inviteId')
  .get(function (req, res) {
    res.status(200).json(req.invite);
  });
```

And the following simple router params:

```
router.param('inviteToken', function (req, res, next, inviteToken) {
  console.log('inviteToken');
  // populate req.invite
  next();
});

router.param('inviteId', function (req, res, next, inviteId) {
  console.log('inviteId');
  // populate req.invite
  next();
});
```

However when I try to fetch an invite by token the inviteId param handler is always triggered first with the literal value `"token"`. Is there an issue with the way I've set up the routes and params?

**Update 1** For more clarification

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Route order definition matters, so the best practice is to go from most specific to most grabby.

```
app.get('/invite/token/:token', tokenHandler);
app.get('/invite/:inviteId', inviteHandler);
```

where `tokenHandler` and `inviteHandler` are appropriately formatted callback functions.

Comment: I've changed the router to the match order you suggested but the result is the same, the token route is never reached.

Comment: Your statement here doesn't match what you said in the question.  In the question, you were talking about the param handler, but your comment here is the token route. Am I misunderstanding?

Comment: That was my mistake, I meant the handler. I created a stripped down version of my problem without my application logic and the results are as you described so the issue must be elsewhere. I will accept your answer.